# В каких случаях невозможно выполнение деструктора класса php?

Tags: php, ооп

Как известно из документации при описании деструктора мы не можем гарантирвоать порядок его выполнения. Однако по факту, мы не можем гарантировать и просто факт его исполнения. Например деструктор не будет выполнен при переполнении памяти на сервере. Какие еще примеры ситуаций, в которых деструктор может не выполнится вы можете назвать?

Comment: _Какие еще примеры ситуаций, в которых деструктор может не выполнится вы можете назвать?_ -- если не ошибаюсь, деструктор  так же не вызывается, если код программы был завершён конструкцией exit;

Comment: Это неверно. http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.decon.php Вот здесь четко прописано что деструктор выполниться при exit()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По итогу исследования выделил следующее случаи:

1. Exit вызван в другом деструкторе.
2. Если другой деструктор бросает исключение.
3. Если мы пытаемся обработать исключение в деструкторе.
4. При получении SIGTERM в случае запуска через CLI.
5. Fatal Error

Буду рад, если кто-то решит дополнить.

Comment: год прошёл. Никто не дополнил((

Comment: если удалить скрипт